# Not able to build LINQ query

Tags: linq

### EmployeeData

1. EmpID
2. Prefix
3. FName
4. MName
5. LName
6. Suffix
7. Deparment
8. Address*
9. Phone*
10. CustomField*

### Address

1. Line1
2. Line2
3. Line3
4. City
5. State
6. Zip

How would I find all Employee who stays in the city = "Boston"? What will be the Linq query assuming EmployeeData is an Entity object and that entity Address can be a collection?

I tried this and the result returned nothing, but there are records with the city = "Boston":

```
var result = empQuery.Select(a => a.Address.Where(f => f.city.ToString().ToLower() == "boston"));
```

Comment: `employees.Where(e => e.Address.City == "Boston")` ?

Comment: You need to show us the code that you tried, or else we cannot help. Please see [ask]. Also don't feed us irrelevant stuff, `Phone` and `CustomField` can and should be removed from this question.

Comment: In your edit: `"I tried this and didn't work"` - What "didn't work" about it?  How *specifically* did it fail?  If you want objects where the `Address.City` property is `"Boston"` then you would compare that property with the string value `"Boston"`.  If something "isn't working" then you need to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should do the same thing:

```
var queryEmployees = employees.Where(emp => emp.Address.City == "Boston")


var queryEmployees = from emp in employees where emp.Adress.City == "Boston"
                    select emp;
```

Edit: Since you have a collection of Address for each Employee, you can query like this:

```
var result = from x in employees from y in x.Adress where y.City == "Boston" select x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't get the city like the way you did. Address is IEnumerable and I have to explicitly call it.